# Regarding issue org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present: A script on this page may be busy

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am currently using Java webdriver 2.53.1 for firefox version 2.46.0. I am getting this below error when run my script for a long time. Since I have different profiles to run multiple scripts at a time using same browser. this firefox browser seems getting crashed.

Please find below error details

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present: A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

Script: https://website/js/jq…596b2b8fa35fe3a634ea342d7c3.js:1
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'MACHINE NAME', ip: 'Ip address', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=47.0.2, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 39cfd1aa-1d74-4b18-bdcd-5255a2b90127
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor51.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Also I have applied two solutions 
say
1.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilites = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilites.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR,UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilites);
```

2. as per the below link
   https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjf4_vy-9rUAhXEEbwKHY8_CTUQFghBMAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fkb%2Fwarning-unresponsive-script&usg=AFQjCNGh0FhTTjSvFduBRRe36UJCGXz8qA

But still the issues seems not fixed on mt script.

Could anyone provide a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This error from my experience is only thrown when you are trying to do a page navigation but have not handled an on screen alert. You need to user the `IAlert` class to accept or dismiss this alert to continue.

First find what command is triggering the alert, then handle the alert.

If you elaborate more on your issue I may be able to help more, it would be helpful if you included the selenium code that is causing this exception.

Here are some functions I use to deal with alerts.

```
public void AcceptAlert()
{
    try
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
        IAlert alert = Driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
        alert.Accept();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
}
public void DismissAlert()
{
    try
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
        IAlert alert = Driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
        alert.Dismiss();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Debug(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is not specific function to get this error. I am basically entering texts on the text box and I got this error. Now one more thing is I have two different repositories on same machine with different profiles. I use same firefox Browser (Same installation path) to test all my scripts. I may two tests at a time. Does this has created the issue? Thanks for your code, Is there anyway I can use this code which is common to all functions say if driver comes up with error I mentioned and then it should go through your code to solve the issue? Please enlighten me